# nginx runing as a service return 404 not found page but works fine with "sudo nginx"

Tags: php, linux, nginx, service

`$ sudo service nginx start` always return 404 Not found page when i'm tring to acees my server.

`$ sudo nginx` works fine

`$ sudo nginx -t` configuration is ok

I don't have `$ sudo servige nginx reload` option, only `force-reload`

i'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with nginx 1.6.2, and i want to run nginx as a service, any ideas why my configuration is not loaded when nginx is started as a service?

Comment: I don't get how restarting nginx connected to 404?

Comment: likely there's something different in the configuration being used by the service start. Look at the service script ( typically /etc/init.d/Xxxx) and find out what arguments (and environment variables) are being used to invoke it. Then compare to your shell invocation and environment.